# How can you check for a specific instance of an App using Powershell/CMD?

Tags: powershell, shell, testing, command-line, automation

I'm working on some *automation testing* for a test app I developed. Using Powershell, I need to **identify if a certain instance of the application is running**. Currently, I can only find out ways to determine if the Application itself is running, not a specific instance of the application.

For example, see picture below:
[image: Task Manager with Application]

The "SDX Test App" is the application itself. From the picture, you can see there's two instance of the test app (the top one is an error popup dialogue).

I need a way **through Powershell** to detect if the **"Assertion Failure" instance is running**.

When I right click on that instance, there is no option for "Properties" or anything like that.

Does anyone have a method of checking this? It would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the `MainWindowTitle` and/or `CommandLine` properties to differentiate between processes with the same name:

```
# List the different instances of notepad++
Get-Process -Name notepad++ | Select-Object ProcessName,MainWindowTitle,CommandLine
```

```
ProcessName MainWindowTitle        CommandLine
----------- ---------------        -----------
notepad++   C:\A\A.txt - Notepad++ "C:\Program File…"
notepad++   C:\B\B.txt - Notepad++ "C:\Program File…" "C:\B\B.txt"
```

From there you can write a basic test. For example:

```
# Check for assertion failure window:
if ( (Get-Process -Name "SDX Test App").MainWindowTitle -like "Assertion Failure*" ) {
  Write-Output "It's running!"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is an extremely clean and easy solution. I appreciate it!